# Several died after update ros-fuerte-navigation version 1.8.3

Tags: navigation, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros community,

After the last update in ros fuerte, move_base and map_server die after launch them with launch apps [1][2] that used to work properly.

They doesn't give much information, for instance:

```
[move_base-3] process has died [pid 10283, exit code -4, [...]
```

I tried to find a solution and I haven't found any.

This is the configuration of the system:

- Ubuntu 12.04 64bit
- ROS Fuerte
- ros-fuerte-navigation 1.8.3-s1367591379~precise

Has anybody found a similar problem? or have a clue of a possible problem/solution?

Thanks in advance,

see you saturday!

[1] http://devel.iri.upc.edu/pub/labrobotica/ros/iri-ros-pkg/stacks/iri_teaching/upc_mobrob/launch/fuerte/sim_stage_navigation.launch

[2] http://devel.iri.upc.edu/pub/labrobotica/ros/iri-ros-pkg/stacks/iri_teaching/upc_mobrob/launch/fuerte/sim_move_base.launch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62453/several-died-after-update-ros-fuerte-navigation-version-1.8.3/) by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 843 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-05-09**:
I am having major problems since the last Fuerte update as well.  Every node I try and run that uses pcl is crashing.  I'm guessing something went wrong during packaging.  I filed a bug report with perception_pcl (wrong place) [error here](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/10)

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2013-05-14**:
Thanks @jarvisschultz, I followed the instructions of the patch there and it worked.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-27**:
What does the log file for the move-base node contain?

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2013-05-28**:
Hi Tully, It says
log file: /home/chaplin/.ros/log/3a0dfd2e-c790-11e2-9b26-c417fe1f097c/move_base-3*.log
but there's not actual log file and the logs don't give other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How did you get the latest Fuerte update?  Did you do it with "apt-get update" and "apt-get install ..." or "apt-get upgrade"?  I have seen problems with version dependencies not being modeled super carefully in the ROS debian packages (they tell me it is difficult, and I don't doubt it).

The result is they recommend to always upgrade by doing

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

"dist-upgrade" upgrades every package in your system to the latest available.  It takes longer, but is more reliable with ROS packages.

If all that does not help, I usually follow [the instructions here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) to run just the node in question in gdb, so I can get a stack trace.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2013-05-09**:
Thank you, I'll try it as soon as I can. And yes, I did upgrade not dist-upgrade.

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2013-05-13**:
Hi, this solution hasn't worked, but thanks for the answer, it may be useful another time.